# eccentricity of the nine-point conic and the Gergonne-Steiner Conic

Tags: conic-sections, quadrilateral

I read from [here](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=5508&pid=50762) that the [nine-point conic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-point_conic) ([QA-Co1](https://www.chrisvantienhoven.nl/qa-items/qa-conics/qa-co1)) of a quadrangle $ABCD$ has eccentricity $e$ satisfying
$$\frac{{{{({e^2} - 2)}^2}}}{{{e^2} - 1}} = \frac{{{{\sin }^2}(A + C)}}{{\sin A\sin B\sin C\sin D}}\tag1$$
I read from [here](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/forum.php?mod=redirect&goto=findpost&ptid=10228&pid=50681) that the Gergonne-Steiner Conic ([QA-CO3](https://chrisvantienhoven.nl/other-quadrangle-objects/15-mathematics/quadrangle-objects/artikelen-qa/78-qa-co3.html)) of a quadrangle $ABCD$ has eccentricity $e$ satisfying
$$\frac{{{e^4}}}{{1 - {e^2}}} = \frac{{{{\sin }^2}(A + C)}}{{\sin A\sin B\sin C\sin D}}\tag2$$
The author of the posts gave a [proof](http://kuing.infinityfreeapp.com/data/attachment/forum/202302/17/110242ion93ys818l2t18o.png) of (2) which is excerpt from his unpublished [book](https://bbs.emath.ac.cn/thread-18088-1-1.html). The proof uses formulas in context of Chapter 3.3 but I don't have access to it.

I hope to see proof of (1) and (2) and see why the right hand side of them are the same.